C++ character encoding issue
Hello when I try to run this code in visual studio 2022:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "შეიყვანე პირველი ციფრი : ";
}

terminal that launches afterwards shows ???????????? instead of შეიყვანე პირველი ციფრი(GEORGIAN Language) so I am curious what is the problem
I tried changing the Unicode to utf-8 in property pages settings for C/C++ in command lines by adding /utf-8 but it did not work

You have to ensure that code has correct encoding, but also the console.

The /utf-8 options changes the source encoding, but does nothing to whatever cout is connected to.

To use non-ASCII characters in a narrow string literal and output it correctly, you have to make sure the source file, compiler, and console all agree on the same encoding. In this case, you should make sure that 1) your source file is saved as UTF-8 (and/or prefix the string literal with u8"..."); 2) you have configured the compiler to process the source file as UTF-8; and 3) you have configured the console to expect UTF-8 output.  Otherwise, use a wide string literal instead (L"..."), use std::wcout, and configure the console for UTF-16 output.

@RemyLebeau The source file encoding ought to not matter as long as the compiler is told the correct source file encoding and that encoding can represent the characters. The source character set encoding is completely separated from the execution character set encoding. The character literal prefix has nothing to do with the source encoding.

@BoP According to documentation /utf-8 sets both source encoding as well as the execution character set encoding to UTF-8. The terminal (or other output device) still needs to be configured for UTF-8, but it is the execution character set encoding that matters here, not the source one. The source character set encoding can be different (as long as the characters are representable), but obviously it must actually be encoded according to what the compiler is told.

Are you using Microsoft's new Windows Terminal that support UTF-8?

The issue here is not your program, that might be perfect. This issue is what the device you are displaying your text on is capable of. If the terminal is not capable of displaying Georgian text (or has not been set up correctly to do so) then it doesn't matter how good your program is, it's not going to work.

This question is similar to: How to print UTF-8 strings to std::cout on Windows?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Do you see a sequence of regular ? (U+003F,  Question Mark) in the output, or something like �������� i.e. a sequence of Glyph 0: the .notdef glyph?

Is there any update? Are you using WIn10 terminal or Win11 terminal?

The question is similar to an existing question, which contains much more details, and also provides solutions. Moreover, a lot of questions for clarification were posted, without response
